# How is it that $-1/2$ can be factored outside of $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, factoring, substitution

If you are given

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$$

How is it that $-\frac{1}{2}$ can be factored outside of the integral?

The exponent in the denominator is $\frac{1}{2}$, but I do not see where 2 is in the denominator.

Comment: What $\frac{1}{2}$ would you factor out? Could you give the factorization you do not understand? Also, did your integral come with bounds?

Comment: @BillO'Haran it appears that the integral did not come with bounds, otherwise they would be specified beneath and above the integral sign, at least to my understanding. The integral can also be written as $\int (x)(1-x^2)^\frac{-1}{2}dx$

Comment: It's a balancing of *wants* and *needs*. Anticipating the Chain Rule, you want $-2x$ in the numerator; that is, you *want to* multiply by $-2$. In order to not change the value of things, you *need to* also multiply by $-1/2$ (because $(-2)(-1/2) = 1$, and multiplying by $1$ is like not doing anything). Being clever, you can put the *wanted* factor inside the integral (where it helps you), and the *needed* factor outside (where it's out of the way).

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ since $$(1-x^2)'=-2x$$

Comment: I do not understand how you have introduced -$\frac {1}{2}$ , this is why I am asking this question. You are assuming I know too much, when in fact I know nothing.

Comment: @sawreals2 Um... Dr. Sonnhard is essentially multiplying the whole expression by $1$ since multiplying by $1$ is an identity equation and doesn't change anything. He's rewritten $1$ as $\tfrac {-2}{-2}$ and factored the numerator into the integrand and the denominator out. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$

Let $1-x^2=u$ => Differentiate with respect to 'x'

$dx=\frac{du}{-2x}$

Now, $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt {u}}$$\frac{du}{-2x}$

$\frac{-1}{2}$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt {u}}du$

=$-\sqrt {u}+C$

Substituting u=$\sqrt {1-x^2}$, then we get

$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$
=$-\sqrt {1-x^2}+C$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question right, but in order to factor out a $-\frac 12$, you need to multiply by $-2$ because $-2\times-\frac 12=1$.$$\begin{align*}\int\frac {x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & =1\cdot\int\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\ & =\frac {-2}{-2}\int\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\ & =\frac 1{-2}\int\frac {-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\ & =-\frac 12\int\frac {-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\end{align*}$$As for why we would do that, it's because the derivative of $1-x^2$ is $-2x$ which is the numerator (i.e integrating by u-substitution)

Comment: So it is a matter of rationalization?

Comment: I think one possible reason for my confusion could be attributed to why the u-substitution is u = $1 - x^2$ and not u = $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: It is always better to take the equation within square root or within the brackets. However, you can take with square root but it becomes little complicated.

Comment: @sawreals2 It's better to take $u$ as the base $u=1-x^2$ because our numerator of the integrand has an $x$ term, and experience tells us that differentiating $x^2$ w.r.t $x$ will give us $2x$ which is just a factor of two away from our desired result. You can take $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but what results is probably more complicated or not feasible.